# How can I simplify the nested name specifier in C++?

Tags: c++, inner-classes

Assume I have the following code:

```
template<bool t>
class A{
  class B{
    class C{
      public:
        void foo();
    };
  };
};

template<bool t>
void A<t>::B::C::foo() {
// some code
}
```

when writing the definition of this function `foo()` , I wish to avoid writing the too-long nested name specifier `A<t>::B::C::` but use something like `aShortAlias<t>::foo()` instead. Is this possible with C++?

Apparently using `using aShrtAlias<t> = typename A<t>::B::C` doesn't work. And I don't really want to use a `#define` as a workaround since it only do text-replacement(maybe there is some justification for `#define` here?).

Comment: `template<bool t>
class A{
  class B{
    class C{
      private:
        void foo() { /* some code here */ }
    };
  };
};`  -- also -- `foo()`  can be only called on the instance of C, how are you going to do that :)

Comment: I can always add more contents to get the whole stuff make sense, can't I?

Comment: As it is now, I think there is no legal way to call `foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `using`:

```
template <bool T>
using aShortAlias = A<T>::B::C
```

Comment: It doesn't actually let you define the member function, though and `typename` is probably required.

Comment: This doesn't allow one to define the member function. Even with a `typename`. Because this `aShortAlias` is not actually a type.

Answer (score 1):

While you can create an alias:

```
template<bool T>
using X = typename A<T>::B::C;
```

You cannot use that alias as a specifier in the declaration:

```
template<bool T>
void X<T>::foo()   // not allowed; doesn't compile
{
   ...
}
```

Afaik you need to use the fully qualified name in the declaration.

Comment: To the edit replacing "declaration" with "definition": A definition is always a declaration also. And the alias can't be used as a specifier in the declaration part of the definition if you will. You can perfectly fine use it in the definition body, or as a parameter type etc.

Comment: @uneven_mark no worries. I am not 100% sure myself that the terminology I used is correct.

Comment: Technically, going by the standard, I suppose it is the *declarator* of the *function-definition*, the latter of which is also a *declaration*, although the *function-body* seems to be part of the *declaration* and *function-definition*, if I read the grammar correctly. In any case I understand what you meant now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is:

```
template <bool T> using aShortAlias = typename A<T>::B::C;

template<> void aShortAlias<false>::foo() {
}
template<> void aShortAlias<true>::foo() {
}
```

Comment: and if you have anything other than `bool`?

Comment: Ah I see your point! Luckily I don't have anything other than `bool` at this moment. If the template variables are more general(e.g. `int`) then this approach doesn't really work out.